# Sql server query to get Data

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a requirement where I need to insert records with different hashvalue for a particular EmpID. Below are some sample values from Staging and Master records. Staging gets values every week and needs to insert values into master depending on the ID and hashvalue and when all records are processed, table is truncated.

```
Week 1 in staging: EMpd ID Hash Value
    1000    1; 2000    2
2 records gets inserted in master

Week2 in staging: EMPID hashvalues
              1000   -3
              2000    2
              3000    5
Master should have 1000  1;1000   -3; 2000 2; 3000  5
Week 3 in staging: EMPID hashvalues
               1000  -5
               2000  -9
               3000   5
Master should have 1000  1;1000   -3; 1000   -5;2000 2; 2000 -9;3000  5


I have tried doing 
insert into EMP_MASTER (EMPID,EMPNAME,hashValue)
select mas.*,stg.hashvalue FROM [EMP_master] mas (nolock) 
INNER JOIN [EMP_staging] stg (nolock) ON mas.EMPID = stg.EMPID
WHERE mas.hashvalue != stg.hashvalue and not exists 
(select 1 from [EMP_Master](nolock) 
where EMPID=stg.EMPID and hashValue=stg.hashvalue )  order by EMPID;
```

This gives duplicate values for 1000. Can anyone help me?
Thanks
MR

Answer (score 0):

basically it is a simple select rows with no matching entry in another table. 
you could try this:

```
 insert into EMP_MASTER (EMPID,hashValue)
    SELECT t1.EMPID, t1.hashValue
    FROM staging t1
        LEFT JOIN master t2 ON t1.EMPID = t2.EMPID AND t1.hashValue = t2.hashValue
    WHERE t2.EMPID IS NULL
```